Crear un Gancho en Windows
Realmente estoy creando un emulador de Xbox 360, y necesito ocultar el cursor por completo sin perder el funcionamiento, ejmplo si ejecuto el script de emulador, el cursor ocultarse, pero sin perder el movimiento, para que el emulador.. capture el movimiento del mouse oculto.. para que hago para que no el cursor no interefiera en los juegos ya que los juegos detectan el cursor y cambia a teclado y raton y no dejan funcionar correctamente el emulador.

Que modulo estás usando para crear el emulador?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Necesito ocultar el Cursor (Mouse) al ejecutar el script en python.. ocultarlo totalmente, o dejarlo fijo. sin que se mueva visualmente, pero que en mi script, intercepte el movimiento del cursor Fijo. Ejemplo: el Cursor que se quede Fijo en la pantalla al ejecutar el Script, pero en la consola, mientras muevo el cursor, me vaya diciendo que cordenadas se esta moviendo internamente.. seria crear un Gancho de windows?

estoy usando VGamePad y ViGemBus

Crea un cursor transparente
